# Error in PostgreSQL/PostGIS Access to offline bands disabled

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using postgis functions i.e. ST_Clip, ST_PixelHeight.

But I am getting this error -

> ERROR: rt_raster_load_offline_data: Access to offline bands disabled

Actually, I have loaded my raster to postgis using

> raster2pgsql

In raster2pgsql I have used -R option for saving only the metadata of the raster and path location to the raster in the database (not the pixels).

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you set the environment variables to enable rasters ?

> As of PostGIS 2.1.3, out-of-db rasters and all raster drivers are disabled by default. In order to re-enable these, you need to set the following environment variables: POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS and POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS in the server environment.
>
> If you want to enable offline raster:
>
> POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS=1
>     Any other setting or no setting at all will disable out of db rasters.
>
> In order to enable all GDAL drivers available in your GDAL install, set this environment variable as follows
>
> POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=ENABLE_ALL

From http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_short_version

Comment: In recent versions of PostGIS, these can be set at the database or cluster level instead of using environment variables. `ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers='GTiff'; ALTER SYSTEM SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters='on'; SELECT pg_reload_conf();`